# Potted tulips are drying up

Tags: indoors, tulips

This is the first time I bought tulip bulbs and I kept them inside, beside the window.
Recently I got flowers.
But, the flowers are there for only 2-3 days before they started drying up.
Is this normal ? Or, am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Are you giving water?

Comment: Do you mean tulip bulbs planted in potting soil in a pot? Did you buy them like that, or pot them up yourself?

Comment: What’s the temperature in your house and how much sun do they get?

Comment: since the original author is not responding with new information i think this is too open of a question and not all that useful other than to say that potted tulips usually are forced for one season and then discarded.  the conditions those forced plants experience vary so much you would have to track the supplier/chain - let alone figure out how the person asking the question treated them.

Answer (score -1):

I know that tulip bulbs before planting have to stay for a while in the cold either in the refrigerator or simply planted in the garden during the winter. Then we can plant them in pots kept in the house

Comment: But that’s only relevant to coax them to sprout, it’s absolutely not related to how long the flowers last. Are you sure you are *answering the question*?

Comment: You think what you want, but i know what i'm talking about. For good germination and healthy flowers, tulip bulbs should stay for at least two months at low temperature.

Comment: Do you have a citation to back up your answer? I've never heard of a link between the amount of time forcing tulip bulbs and how long the flowers last, and I'd be interested to read more about the subject. Thanks!